# While Loop to kill chrome and open another chrome depending on condition

Tags: bash, while-loop, raspberry-pi

I have the following 3 scripts (perhaps I could make it one script but my mind isn't seeing the logic :))

Here is the first script (chkEvents.sh). which will check if a file has content or not and launch a browser accordingly. They also load a background loop to see if the content changes.

```
#!/bin/bash  

baseEvent=$(cat EVENTS.CSV)
if [ -z "$baseEvent" ]
then
        ./chkifnoEvents.sh &
        exec startx /usr/bin/chromium-browser --kiosk --app=http://10.0.1.91/digisign-portrait-v8-lite/noEvents.html
else
        ./chkifactEvents.sh &
        exec startx /usr/bin/chromium-browser --kiosk --app=http://10.0.1.91/digisign-portrait-v8-lite/index.html
fi
```

Second script is the background check (chkifnoEvents.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
pkill chkifactEvents.sh
while :
do
  chkEvents=$(cat EVENTS.CSV)
  if [ -z "$chkEvents" ]
  then
    sleep 2
    echo no events still
  else
    echo events found killing chrome
    pkill chromium-browse
    sleep 3
    break
  fi
done
sleep 1
exec ./chkEvents.sh
```

Third is similar to second (chkifactEvents.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
pkill chkifnoEvents.sh
while :
do
  chkEvents=$(cat EVENTS.CSV)
  if [ -z "$chkEvents" ];
  then
    echo Events File is Empty killing chrome
    pkill chromium-browse
    sleep 3
    break
  fi
done
sleep 1
exec ./chkEvents.sh
```

What I am expecting to happen is that the browser gets killed if the EVENTS.CSV file is empty or not. Mind you this is launching without a desktop manager. However when the content changes... it doesn't launch the browser. i get the following errors:

```
xinit: connection to X server lost
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: connection refused
xinit: server error
```

Please help. The goal is to keep a browser up on the screen based if a file is empty or not.

**Edit: I forgot to mention that the script launches chromium but when it kills it, it fails to relaunch the new instance**

**Edit: I'm using a raspberry pi running the latest jessie lite. I don't have a desktop manager and all that was installed was chromium-browser and Xorg server. The script runs on VT1 and should stay there.**

**Resolution: I can't believe how simple it was to fixed my issue.**

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
./chkEvents.sh
done
```

chkEvents.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
killall chkif*
baseEvent=$(cat EVENTS.CSV)
if [ -z "$baseEvent" ]
then
    ./chkifnoEvents.sh &
    exec startx /usr/bin/chromium-browser --kiosk --app=http://10.0.1.91/digisign-portrait-v8-lite/
else
    ./chkifactEvents.sh &
    exec startx /usr/bin/chromium-browser --kiosk --app=http://10.0.1.91/digisign-portrait-v8-lite/
fi
```

chkifnoEvents.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
  chkEvents=$(cat EVENTS.CSV)
  if [ -z "$chkEvents" ]
  then
    sleep 2
    echo no events still
  else
    pkill chromium-browse
    break
  fi
done
```

chkifactEvents.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
  chkEvents=$(cat EVENTS.CSV)
  if [ -z "$chkEvents" ];
  then
      pkill chromium-browse
      break
  fi
done
```

Sometimes you just need to take a step back and stop thinking about it. Figured then why don't just keep the script in a loop instead of the process. Then kill it. The condition will be met. I think ultimately the problem was with the background processes launching a script the brings up a UI.

Comment: The error message hints at the X11 init going wrong, which makes me believe the whole surrounding scriptery is not at fault (making your question about the wrong thing entirely, and most of the posted code irrelevant). What happens if you run the `exec startx /usr/bin/chromium-browser ...` line in isolation? (My guess is, the very same error message popping up.)

Comment: chromium runs.. Its when it is killed that it fails to relaunch

Comment: So try `pkill chromium-browse && sleep 3 && exec startx /usr/bin/chromium-browser ...`. Reduce the amount of code required. Build a [mcve]. I am still very sure it's not really related to your looping. (This hack-away-and-retry approach is a very valid debugging technique.)

Comment: I will try that and thanks for the MCVE. I will post back.

Comment: My next attempt would be to check if it's related to chromium, or if it happens as well when using `xterm` or something generic like that. (Ruling out a chromium-related problem, and allowing people *without* chromium installed to *still* reproduce your problem. Like me. ;-) )